# ORDER BY clause failed

Tags: java, oracle, sql-order-by

My `ORDER BY` clause failed. Code:

```
try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kabumbu?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "****");
            String q = "select player_id, sum(number_of_goals) as 'Number of Goals',school_name "
                    + "from goal_scorers g , schools s "
                    + "where g.school_id = s.school_id "
                    + "group by g.player_id "
                    + "ORDER BY number_of_goals DESC";
            PreparedStatement pstm = conn.prepareStatement(q);
            ResultSet rs = null;
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();

            jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
```

Comment: An explanation of the actual problem with that code (like an Exception message) would be helpful.

Comment: it was the statement on order by sum(number_of_goals)... i missed the "sum" part and works well now... Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You query is `sum(number_of_goals)` so the [order by](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html) should use the same:

```
ORDER BY sum(number_of_goals)
```

instead of `ORDER BY number_of_goals`

Or by number of column (2)

```
ORDER BY 2
```

> ORDER BY { column-Name | ColumnPosition | Expression }
>
> **column-Name**
>
> Refers to the names visible from the SelectItems in the underlying query of the SELECT statement. The column-Name that you specify in the ORDER BY clause does not need to be the SELECT list.
>
> **ColumnPosition**
>
> An integer that identifies the number of the column in the SelectItems in the underlying query of the SELECT statement. ColumnPosition must be greater than 0 and not greater than the number of columns in the result table. In other words, if you want to order by a column, that column must be specified in the SELECT list.
>
> **Expression**
>   A sort key expression, such as numeric, string, and datetime expressions. Expression can also be a row value expression such as a scalar subquery or case expression.